# android webview top bar

Tags: android, webview

My problem: When I hold my finger on the screen for a few seconds, the top bar appears.
It causes an error, as it is removed?

P.S. `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

[My screenshot](http://dilibrary.com.ua/device-2012-11-26-195402.png)

[Second screenshot](http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=30d3f3b036b3b9cc4a1a2c504fa069fc)

this is my manifest, android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" - gives an error

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dred.mytest_2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_72"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

I seem to have found the source of the problem, I open the webview swf file, that he calls this menu (when I open this html menu does not appear)

Comment: what target is it ? (ps your image does not load)

Comment: the top bar on the image is not the system top bar (which is on the bottom.) also, the theme for android 4 would probably best be Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen

Comment: you need to make sure thats code is within you activity within your Manifest and it should never appear. You would need to put it within every sepearte activity that you are using. If that does not work, try removing .FullScreen from the end.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this can solve your problem. I'm unable to see the images attached, as i have problem with access privileges.

```
webview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I did as you wrote, the bar is still there

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your application section of your manifest to the below:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_72"
    android:label="@string/app_name"> 
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" > 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: try changing your target and min SdkVersion to 7 for both, whilst keeping the above code within your manifest

Comment: Also, have you tested this on an acutal device?

Comment: Owned problem in rendering swf file, it calls the menu and handles long press
how to avoid it?